# Using NLog & Console Logging Together in .Net Core Console App

Tags: c#, .net-core, console-application, nlog

Is there any implementation to use Nlog and .Net Core Console Logging in a encapsulated logger. For example, LoggingService has Nlog factory and Console Logging ability.
Eg `LoggingService.Debug` writes to both the Nlog log file and console. Or is there any other approach to handle these type of problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me know if I'm misunderstanding the question, but NLog itself supports writing to multiple targets (i.e. both the console and to a log file):

Per https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Tutorial#configure-nlog-targets-for-output :

```
var config = new NLog.Config.LoggingConfiguration();

// Targets where to log to: File and Console
var logfile = new NLog.Targets.FileTarget("logfile") { FileName = "file.txt" };
var logconsole = new NLog.Targets.ConsoleTarget("logconsole");

// Rules for mapping loggers to targets            
config.AddRule(LogLevel.Info, LogLevel.Fatal, logconsole);
config.AddRule(LogLevel.Debug, LogLevel.Fatal, logfile);

// Apply config           
NLog.LogManager.Configuration = config;
```

With NET Core, you can also take advantage of Microsoft's logging abstractions via the NLog provider for `Microsoft.Logging.Extensions`:

https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging